# MATLAB, I want to fill a 15 column matrix with a few fixed selected values such that all combinations are covered

Tags: matlab

Example, I wish to fill a 15 column matrix with the values 0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25,0,0,0 .....( 11 columns with zeros) so that all possible column combinations are filled. In this example I am using 4 columns with 0.25 and the other 11 col's with 0's.

Result should look like :-

```
0.25  0.25  0.25  0.25  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00 .......
0.25  0.25  0.25  0.00  0.25  0.00  0.00  0.00 .......
0.25  0.25  0.25  0.00  0.00  0.25  0.00  0.00 .......

 .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .   .......
 .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .   .......
0.25  0.25  0.00  0.25  0.25  0.00  0.00  0.00 .......
0.25  0.25  0.00  0.25  0.00  0.25  0.00  0.00 ....... etc, etc.
```

When using "perms" (limited to 10 elements anyway ) it treats each "0" as if they are unique hence I get multiple rows that are the same.  The "unique" function works fine if less than 10 elements but I need to use more than that.  Appreciate any assistance, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `accumarray` is your friend in this case. I'll do a simpler example - creating a six column matrix with exactly two columns filled and the rest zero.

First, we get the list of horizontal indices that you want to be filled using `nchoosek`

```
x = nchoosek(1:6, 2);
```

Now get the vertical coordinates

```
y = repmat((1:size(x,1))', 1, 2);
```

Finally, use `accumarray` to create the desired matrix

```
z = accummarray([y(:), x(:)], 0.5);
```

The result is

```
>> z
z =
    0.5000    0.5000         0         0         0         0
    0.5000         0    0.5000         0         0         0
    0.5000         0         0    0.5000         0         0
    0.5000         0         0         0    0.5000         0
    0.5000         0         0         0         0    0.5000
         0    0.5000    0.5000         0         0         0
         0    0.5000         0    0.5000         0         0
         0    0.5000         0         0    0.5000         0
         0    0.5000         0         0         0    0.5000
         0         0    0.5000    0.5000         0         0
         0         0    0.5000         0    0.5000         0
         0         0    0.5000         0         0    0.5000
         0         0         0    0.5000    0.5000         0
         0         0         0    0.5000         0    0.5000
         0         0         0         0    0.5000    0.5000
```

Packaging it up as a function, you get

```
function z = combinations(N, K)

    x = nchoosek(N, K);
    y = repmat((1:size(x,1))', 1, K);
    z = accumarray([y(:), x(:)], 1);

end
```

Comment: very nice, +1 ... (you have a typo in the 3rd row of code (accummarray...) )

Comment: Thank you both for responding. Solutions work well. Importantly I have learned, and was a good experience. Great site.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [combn](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7147-combn-4-3) from the file exchange.

For example:

```
c      = combn([0 0.25],15);  
ind    = find(sum(c')==1);
Result = c(ind,:)
```

The tactic here is probably an overkill but it's so simple and easy to implement, I thought to myself, why not?

First, get all possible combinations of `0` and `0.25` for a vector of length 15 (there are 2^15 of those), as done in the first line, where we obtain a [2^15 x 15] matrix (`c`). Then we find rows in `c` of that sum up to 1, meaning that the value 0.25 appears exactly four times. Then, use this back in `c` and  Voilà!

If you want to obtain `c` yourself (without `combn`), this is how to do it:

```
V = [0 0.25];
a = [0:2^15-1]+(1/2) ;
b = [2.^(1-15:0)] ;
id = rem( floor((a(:) * b(:)')) , 2 ) + 1 ;
c = V(id) ;
```

Comment: I would be worried about this method, for two reasons - first, it creates a very large matrix (`c`) when only a small subsetof it will eventually be required. If you use larger arguments (e.g. 32 and 9 instead of 11 and 4) you will blow the available memory. Secondly, it relies on floating point arithmetic. Try creating a matrix with 11 columns, of which exactly 7 are filled with 1/7 and 4 of which are zero.

Comment: I agree that this is an overkill (and also said so in the answer). as for floating point accuracy, the better thing to do to begin with, is use a binary matrix (logicals), the actual value `0.25` or whatever, is not important here. Still `0.25+0.25+0.25+0.25+0.25==1.25` works and one can istead use other conditions. The best argument for `accumarray` is that it is faster and more elegant.

Comment: Agreed, you can easily get around the floating point problem - a logical matrix would solve it easily.